# Custom Test Case Name in TestNg HTML reports

Tags: testng, integration-testing

I am trying to override the test case name in the testNg HTML report since I am using the data provider and each test data depicts something different. To do this, I added the following:

I am setting the test name using the data provider. My data provider has the relevant test case name.

Here is what I am doing :

```
   @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
   public void setTestName(Method method, Object[] row, ITestContext context) {
     testName.set(row[0].toString()); // row ["<testCaseName1", "..", "....">]
     context.setAttribute("testName", row[0].toString()); // row ["<testCaseName1", "..", "....">]
    }
```

I have tried setting up in the test context too. I see that on console the test case names seem to come different and the correct ones which I am passing in the parameter.

However, in the default testNG HTML report, the test names are not getting changed. If the data provider has 4 different test data, then a particular test which runs 4 times with different test data, is being shown in the report with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ITestResult` to change the name of test in a report. For example this is the complete solution:

Your dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your test class:

```java
package click.webelement;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CustomReportName {

    @DataProvider(name = "db")
    public Object[][] createData() {
        return new Object[][] {{"test 1"}, {"test 2"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "db")
    public void testParameterized(String msg, ITestContext context){
        context.setAttribute("customTestName", "Custom: " + msg);
    }

    @Test
    public void noDataProvider(){

    }

    @AfterMethod()
    public void setTestNameForReport(ITestResult testResult, ITestContext context){
        if(testResult.getMethod().getDataProviderMethod() != null){
            testResult.setTestName(context.getAttribute("customTestName").toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println("No data provider for this method");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works, however, there are few tests which actually don't have a data provider, in such cases the last attributes get overriden. Is there a way to clear these attributes? I tried removing the added attribute in afterTest, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Test attribute for null. See my update. If it is null then it was not set for the test hence no customization applied.

Comment: @Mahima wrong. The proper way would be to check if a method has data provider assigned. Fixed and updated my example.